# Loading large sparknlp pipeline into Apache Spark batch job taking too long

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

I am using SparkNLP from johnsnowlabs for extracting embeddings from my textual data, below is the pipeline. The size of the model is **1.8g** after saving to hdfs

```
embeddings = BertSentenceEmbeddings.pretrained("labse", "xx") \
      .setInputCols("sentence") \
      .setOutputCol("sentence_embeddings")
nlp_pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[document_assembler, sentence_detector, embeddings])
pipeline_model = nlp_pipeline.fit(spark.createDataFrame([[""]]).toDF("text"))
```

I saved the `pipeline_model` into `HDFS` using `pipeline_model.save("hdfs:///<path>")`.

*The above was executed only one time*

In another script, i am loading the stored pipeline from `HDFS` using `pipeline_model =  PretrainedPipeline.from_disk("hdfs:///<path>")`.

The above code loads the model but takes too much. I tested it on the spark local model ( no cluster ) but i had high resource 94g RAM, 32 Cores.

Later, i deployed the script on yarn with 12 Executor each with 3 cores and 7g ram. I assigned driver memory of 10g.

The script again takes too much time just to load the saved model from HDFS.

[image: When the spark reaches at this point, it takes too much time]

*When the spark reaches at this point (see above screenshot), it takes too much time*

I thought of an approach

##### Preloading

The approach which i thought was to somehow pre-load model one time into memory, and when the script wants to apply transformation on dataframe, i can somehow call the reference to the pretrained pipeline and use it on the go, without doing any disk i/o. I searched but i it lead to nowhere.

Please, do let me know what you think of this solution and what would be the best way to achieve this.

Resources on YARN

| NodeName | Count | RAM (each) | Cores (each) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Master Node | 1 | 38g | 8 |
| Secondary Node | 1 | 38 g | 8 |
| Worker Nodes | 4 | 24 g | 4 |
| **Total** | **6** | **172g** | **32** |

Thanks

Comment: I also experienced extremely poor performance with sparknlp labse on Hadoop cpu cluster. Ended up using huggingface pytorch port, up to X100 times faster.

Comment: Also, make sure you're using kryo serialization.

Comment: sure :) with pytorch I just use `df.rdd.mapPartitions` and use the model manually... if you still want to use sparknlp, you might want to check issue #2846 on github, about output not equal to the original model

Comment: Okay, thanks. i used hugging face transformer. Thanks for the tips, it works fine now

Comment: @shay__ what do u think about using the hugging_transformer inside udf? i am using it in udf but the spark job automatically gets killed. 
edit: I checked using system monitor, the ram gets full, i have 100gb RAM and it's get fulled, when i use sparknlp it only uses 28gb of RAM.

Comment: I set `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=16gb` and make sure every partition has no more than 10MB of data

Comment: and in general I wouldn't use udf

Comment: Shay I used that spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=16gb, I am using sparkling water h2o AutoML but the problem now is, when I input the feature matrix in AutoML function to start training, it gets killed automatically. It's like the memory is spilled or something, because my whole ram is being utilized

Comment: try to train on a single data point, just to make sure the issue is not related to scale (but rather to loading the model, etc.)

Comment: okay, i will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @shay__ i did try loading 5 records and the script works fine. I think the issue here is large data, i have 0.5 Million and the records will be growing in the future, may be exponentially. What should be the optimal method for this?

Comment: I mentioned earlier that I repartition the data - in your case try `df.repartition(500)` just to make sure there are ~1k rows per partition. Then (inside `mapPartitions`) I load the entire partition to memory - and pass it to the pytorch model.  Also - how many cores you set per executor? mind that every core will use its own python process.

Comment: @shay__ i have 32 cores, i am using 30 cores, i am using locally on PC, i have 94gb ram.

Comment: after partitioning, the script seems to works partially, when the mapPartitions() is called it gets `ERROR:root:Exception while sending command.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/livy/appcache/application_1623058160826_4782/container_e199_1623058160826_4782_01_000001/py4j-0.10.6-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1062, in send_command
    raise Py4JNetworkError("Answer from Java side is empty")
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: Answer from Java side is empty`

Comment: I'm not sure you can utilize 30 cores in this case... try 5, again just to make sure this is the issue.

Comment: okay , i tried with 5 rows on my Yarn Cluster, the error is same. I am broacasting the model, the size of the model is 1.9gb and then i am using broacasted model inside mapPartition(). i think that is creating the issue

Comment: I dont use broadcast - I use `sc.addFile(hdfs_dir_path, recursive=True)` on the driver and `SparkFiles.get()` on the executors - much better in this case :)

Comment: @shay__ thank you for your awesome support till now, but please can u share me a sample code of loading hugging_face model from `HDFS` using `sc.addFile()` and performing `word_embeddings` . That will be very helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: @shay__ i am using `sentence-transformer` but if my code works with `hugging-face` i can also shift on it.

Comment: please see example as an answer

Comment: @DanialShabbir
Setting `.config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "2000M")` is very important for loading large models especially in PySpark (serialization via Kyro) - `labse` is very large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is a solution based on PyTorch, not SparkNLP. Simplified code:

```
# labse_spark.py

LABSE_MODEL, LABSE_TOKENIZER = None


def transform(spark, df, input_col='text', output_col='output'):
    spark.sparkContext.addFile('hdfs:///path/to/labse_model')
    output_schema = T.StructType(df.schema.fields + [T.StructField(output_col, T.ArrayType(T.FloatType()))])

    rdd = df.rdd.mapPartitions(_map_partitions_func(input_col, output_col))
    res = spark.createDataFrame(data=rdd, schema=output_schema)
    return res


def _map_partitions_func(input_col, output_col):
    def executor_func(rows):
        # load everything to memory (partitions should be small, ~1k rows per partition):
        pandas_df = pd.DataFrame([r.asDict() for r in rows])
        global LABSE_MODEL, LABSE_TOKENIZER
        if not (LABSE_TOKENIZER or LABSE_MODEL):  # should happen once per executor core
            LABSE_TOKENIZER = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(SparkFiles.get('labse_model'))
            LABSE_MODEL = AutoModel.from_pretrained(SparkFiles.get('labse_model'))
        
        # copied from HF model card:
        encoded_input = LABSE_TOKENIZER(
            pandas_df[input_col].tolist(), padding=True, truncation=True, max_length=64, return_tensors='pt')
        with torch.no_grad():
            model_output = LABSE_MODEL(**encoded_input)
        embeddings = model_output.pooler_output
        embeddings = torch.nn.functional.normalize(embeddings)

        pandas_df[output_col] = pd.Series(embeddings.tolist())
        return pandas_df.to_dict('records')

    return executor_func
```